# React Native and JSON file parsing

Tags: android, ios, json, reactjs, mobile

I have some card class like this:

```
export default class TestCard1 extends React.Component {
     render () {
     return (
   <CardView style={styles.card}>
      <Text style = {styles.word}>
      "word"
      </Text>
  </CardView>
);}}
```

This creates a flashcard. I have a list of "words" in a JSON file for which I want to create a flashcard for each word. I can access a word through

```
{rowData.word}
```

I'm not sure how I would "loop through" each word in the json file and create a card from it. Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your json file then use json.stringify to setState in a parent component.  Then use the .map function to loop through each word and pass it into your Card component via props.

```
import words from './words.json'
import Card from './TestCard1'

class parentclass extends React.Component{
  state={
    data: []
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const data = json.stringify(words)
    this.setState({ data })
  }

  render(){
    const words = () => {
      this.state.data.map(word => <Card word={word} />)
    }
    return(
      <View>
        {words()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Your Word component can be restructured to be a "pure" component and only receive data from the parent component constructed above.  You can add styles to the View tag to make it look more like a card.

```
const Card = ({ word }) => (
   <View>
      <Text>
        {word}
      </Text>
  </View>
)
export default Card
```

Comment: Thanks! I would need to set a "word" component in the Card class, right? Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Actually I was thinking that the component you created in your initial post would be the "word" component.  The component I created as an example would be the parent container that receives/sets the json data.  It would then loop through that data and create a "word" component (the component you created) for each word in the word array from your data.

Comment: Ill make an edit to my initial post to show you how you can restructure your component to receive the words prop from the parent component.